# Issue with find command of linux

Tags: linux, find, gnu, gnu-findutils

Continuously getting so many warnings yet my command is working fine.

```
find: `api/PlayersImpl0.smali': No such file or directory
find: `api/PlayersImpl1.smali': No such file or directory
find: `api/TurnBasedMultiplayerImpl0.smali': No such file or directory
find: `api/TurnBasedMultiplayerImpl1.smali': No such file or directory
find: `api/TurnBasedMultiplayerImpl2.smali': No such file or directory
find: `api/TurnBasedMultiplayerImpl3.smali': No such file or directory
```

For file I am using following command :-

```
$cmd  = "find ".'"'.$file_path.'"'." -type f -exec chmod -R 0777 {} +"." > /dev/null";

exec($cmd, $output);
```

For folder I am using following command :-

```
$cmd1  = "find ".'"'.$folder_path.'"'." -type d -exec chmod -R 0777 {} +"." > /dev/null";

exec($cmd1, $output);
```

Note:- exec is a php function to execute shell command. Here I am trying to provide permissions of 777 to all files and folders.

Comment: a PHP warning?  or those "No such file"... ones you pipe to /dev/null?  Confused.

Comment: This is not a PHP warning. If I execute the same command through CLI then also I got the same issue. Means this is something related with find command.

Comment: @Puneet Not sure why you want to provide 777 to all files and folders. That's generally a bad idea, but why not just `chmod -R ...` then, what's the point of the `find`?